# Portable Class Library versioning

Tags: .net, portable-class-library

I am using a VB.NET Portable Class Library to hold my Model objects in an WinRT C#/XAML app. When I consume the Portable Class Library, the version number is always 1.0.0.0 -- I have not found a way to override this with a more relevant value, let alone increment it. The properties pages offer no option I've found, and there is no configuration file for the Portable Class Library.

Does anyone know how to set/increment a version number on a Portable Class Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to the Assembly version?  You can set that with an AssemblyVersionAttribute, which is by default in the AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: That would be the assembly version I am trying to influence. However in the .NET Portable Class Library there is no AssemblyInfo.cs file (at least not created for the project). As such, I am unsure how to implement AssemblyVersionAttribute.

Comment: @JimMarquardt The AssemblyInfo.cs will be under the Properties node/folder in solution explorer.  It will be created when you create a new Portable Class Library project, but if for some reason it's not there you can add the attribute to any source file in your project (you may need a using statement for System.Reflection).

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I found it.